# Keras Predict_generator gives different results each time I execute it

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, generator

I'm trying to use generators in my CNN training but for some reason.
However, when I try to run model.predict_evaluator(), each time I execute it (I'm working in Jupyter Notebook), ¡it gives different results! Same data (stored in folder), same model (I just rerun the same cell)

This block works fine, every time I rerun it, it gives the same metrics

```
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            'keras_data/test',
            batch_size = 1,
            class_mode='categorical')
loss, acc = model.evaluate(test_generator, verbose=1)
print(loss,acc)
```

However, when I  run this cell, it gives different results every time

```
ytest = test_generator.classes
yhat = np.argmax(model.predict_generator(test_generator),axis=1)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

m = confusion_matrix(ytest,yhat)
print(m)
```

It doesn't make any sense! Any ideas on what's happening?

EDIT: here is how I create the generators, just in case the problem is here

```py
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'keras_data/train',
        batch_size=1,
        class_mode='categorical')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'keras_data/val',
        batch_size=1,
        class_mode='categorical')
```

Comment: What is the shape of ytest and yhat?

Comment: @ML_Engine the same, (62,) & (62,). I run the same script without using generators and it worked fine. I don't get why is model.predict_generator providing different results when the same model and test data are being used...

Comment: Set `shuffle = False` for test generator.

Comment: @Frightera this did the trick! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

[Shuffle](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) - Whether to shuffle the data (`default: True`) If set to `False`, sorts the data in alphanumeric order.

From comments

> Set `shuffle = False` for test generator has resolved the issue (paraphrased from Frightera)